# Дополнение объекта динамическими свойствами

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать(**и дополнять**) "глубокий" объект, свойства которого формируются динамически.

В идеале должен работать такой синтаксис:

```
var someObject = {
    '4': {
        reports: {
            participants: ['id', 'name', 'email']
        }
    }
}

var projectId = 5,
    reportGroup = 'statistic',
    reportColumns = 'prizes',

    columns = ['id', 'name', 'score']

someObject[projectId][reportGroup][reportName] = columns
```

Существует ли простой способ создавать глубокую иерархию свойств объектов, и так, чтобы не затереть соседние свойства?

Comment: Есть такая штука, JSON называется, и его парсер, позволяющие такое сделать. Посмотрите, как там оно устроено, и попробуйте так же.

Comment: @Vesper, не могли бы привести пример? Задача не в том, чтобы создавать объект синтаксисом который указан, как идеальный) а просто сделать это наиболее простым способом